# SQL Server SMOs - Installation and Configuration on RHEL 7.7

Tags: sql, sql-server, smo, rhel7

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server 2017 installation on Windows Server 2016 from a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.7 box (both on cloud). This is one of the prerequisites for using the software I need (IBM Content Manager Ondemand). Now, Windows to Windows , I know that we use SMOs at the client and the list is easily available too. I, however , wanted to know if:

1. SMOs (via feature pack?) are needed on the Linux box (and/or the SQL box?) in my case?
2. If yes, what are the prerequisites for that and where do I find the prerequisite rpm packages or .so files?
3. Where do I find the exact .rpm packages for the said SMOs?
4. Anything else that needs to be taken care of?

Apologies if this looks like a noob question. I have literally zero experience with SMOs. Any help shall be really appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Just wanted to add that my searches over the web didn't yield any definitive/conclusive results

Comment: This is the same question you asked [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82db2442-7400-441b-9d0f-4583ce5d54bd/smos-on-rhel-77-prerequisites-and-installation?forum=sqlsmoanddmo). Please avoid posting the same question on different forums as it causes redundant effort for all parties involved. If you do need to do so because you didn't get an answer, at least include a link to your original question.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Appreciate the response and apologies for the duplication. I wasn't sure if the same set of users would be available on both the forums. Just wanted to broaden the audience.